# Mac App store apps use a different user ID so I can't install updates

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, user-account

The OSX Mavericks machine that I use for work has Keynote, Pages, and Numbers installed under the company's Apple ID. (It was purchased in December 2012, pre-Mavericks. It was recently wiped and replaced with an image that I'm guessing already had iWork installed.)

Every day the App store bugs me about installing updates. When I try to do so, I'm prompted for the password, which I don't have. And it won't let me sign in under my personal Apple ID.

[image: "Sign in to download from the Apple Store" prompt. Apple ID field is pre-filled with servicedesk@my-employer.com" and disabled. Password field is empty.]

Is there a way for the helpdesk to transfer these apps to my personal account? Or any other way for me to get the updates aside from opening a helpdesk ticket and waiting patiently?

Comment: Look in your keychain, the password might be there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-buy it with your own account. I don't think there is any way to transfer purchases.